# How to find which controlls that can use the icon attribute? [SAPUI5]

Tags: sapui5, structure

I am looking for **controlls** that can use the `icon` attribute in order to display the `sap-icon://accept`. Till right now i have been using `button` in order to display icons, but as of right now, the border that does make an button, isn't fitting for the task, as such, i am looking for a new controll, that supports `icon` attribute as well as `onPress/onClick` Events.

```
<Button icon="sap-icon://accept"/> //displays the accept icon, however it does an border that makes an Button.
```

Comment: Where / For which purpose, aside from "accepting" something, is the icon exactly used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **sap.ui.core.Icon** class for displaying icons.

It also has press event you can use to click on that icon.

```
<core:Icon src="sap-icon://accept" color="#8875E7" press="handlePress" />
```